# How do you push a docker hub image to an existing Azure web app?

Tags: azure, docker

I do not have privileges to create an Azure Web App, so the admin created one for me.  I need to push an image from Docker Hub to the existing Azure Web App.  The instructions that I have managed to find include using VS Code, going to Docker Hub Registry, Right-Clicking the image and selecting Deploy Image to Azure App Service.  From there I'm prompted to create a new app.  I cannot push the image to the existing app.  How can this be done?

Comment: Review: Consider asking this on http://serverfault instead. Seems more of a system-admin Q than a programmers Q to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AZ CLI to deploy DockerHub image into Azure WebApp

Here is a sample script for Linux Containers.

```
dockerHubContainerPath="<replace-with-docker-container-path>" #format: <username>/<container-or-image>:<tag>

az webapp config container set --docker-custom-image-name $dockerHubContainerPath --name appName --resource-group myResourceGroup
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/cli-linux-docker-aspnetcore?toc=%2Fcli%2Fazure%2Ftoc.json#sample-script